# Certificate Verification: Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate - Chrome on Apple OSX

Tags: macos, apache, google-chrome, ssl

We have installed an Apache Debain Wheezy HTTPS server using a certificate chain that looks like:

```
AddTrust External CA Root -> PositiveSSL CA 2 -> ourdomain.com
```

The SSL part of the Apache configuration file looks like:

```
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ourdomain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ourdomain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/PositiveSSLCA2.crt
    SSLVerifyClient optional
    SSLVerifyDepth 2
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +StrictRequire
    <Location />
            SSLRequireSSL ON
            SSLRenegBufferSize 100000000
    </Location>
```

We have verified the chain both using `openssl verify` locally and using an external verification site. No errors. Besides that the majority of our users can log in perfectly. But one of our users complains he can not log in (Certificate Verification failed). Looking in our server log file we can see the following line for the ip-address associated with that user:

```
Certificate Verification: Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate
```

The user uses OSX and Chrome. What can be wrong or where do we have look to be able to diagnose the problem further?

Comment: The problem was the `SSLVerifyClient optional`. Removing it or setting it to `none` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have sslverifyclient optional, which means that clients may present a client-cert to the webserver, to authenticate themselves. maybe your user has such a cert.
i'm myself new to this, and i think these two items a) sslcertificate of the server and b) client authentication are not dependent from each other...

also im not sure if you may give apache two SSLCertificateChainFile directives.

i hope that helpes a bit.

Comment: You are right. The problem was the SSLVerifyClient option. The two SSLCertificateChainFile are perfectly allright, there is no problem with that. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: i see - confused it with sslcacertificatefile i guess. thanks.